# Select a different Element inside XML Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have managed to get the following to work, this gets all the services in the XML below.

But there is one Service that is outside of the elements, but the rest are in.

I need all services to be in one list.

As you can see from the XML service '1' is outside whereas the '1a' service is inside and the rest are here.

How do I modify the following code or additional code to select all services in one list?

```
var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfService
                     select new RootContainer
                          {
                            Stops = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "Service").Elements(ns + "client").Elements(ns + "services").Elements(ns + "Service")

                                       select new Stops

                                       {

                                           NaptanCode = s.Element(ns + "serviceDescription").Value,
                                           StopName = "/Images/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                                           StopId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                                       }).ToList()
                          }).Single();


        listServices.ItemsSource = routeNames.Stops;
```

xml:
         `<ArrayOfService xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Service z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
     <client z:Id="i3">
       <services>

        <Service z:Id="i5">
          <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>
          <serviceName>1A</serviceName>
          <serviceText>Whitehawk - Mile Oak</serviceText>
        </Service>
       </services>
     </client>
     <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>
     <serviceName>1</serviceName>
   </Service>
  </ArrayOfService>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var routeNames = doc.Descendants(ns + "client").FirstOrDefault().Descendants(ns + "Service").Select(s => new {
                    NaptanCode = s.Element(ns + "serviceDescription").Value,
                    StopName = "/Images/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                    StopId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                }).ToList();
```

to get both level of service use this

```
           var routeNames = doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfService").FirstOrDefault().Elements(ns + "Service").Select(x => new {
                serviceDescription = (string)x.Element(ns + "serviceDescription"),
                serviceName = (string)x.Element(ns + "serviceName"),
                services = x.Descendants(ns + "Service").Select(s => new {
                    NaptanCode = s.Element(ns + "serviceDescription").Value,
                    StopName = "/Images/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                    StopId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

You can enumerate through query results with following

```
foreach (var parentService in routeNames)
{
    foreach (var childService in parentService.services)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This still produces the same result. It just shows 1a and not 1 as well.

Comment: Service 1 is at a higher level then Service 1A,  I modified code to get both levels

Comment: Look again.  You are now getting 1 (not 1A),  The 1A is hidden as a child of 1 and can be opened by pressing the arrow.  1 to 14 are other services that are null.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thanks. So how do I then get the rest of the services from this in a list box?

Comment: Also, I have been trying to select the service, how do you select the service for 1 and 1A.

Comment: routeNames[1].services[0]

Comment: Which answer does that relate to?

Comment: "how do you select the service for 1 and 1A".  The results is a two dimensional array.

Comment: Hi. Ok possible to have an example on how to select the different services? Also the full way to get the services on one list? Thanks

Comment: Why?  One is a child of the other and don't contain same info.

Comment: Why - Because I don't know how to get the listbox to display all the items from the code above. Nor do I know how the routeNames[1].services[0] work. As i have tried this and this does not work.

Comment: Thanks, So if i put the following code in the foreach -    'listServices.ItemsSource = childService.NaptanCode;' this I would expect to list the services, but it doe not produce any of the services.

Comment: The properties are the same names in the query (left of the equal signs).

Comment: Ok thanks. I have got the list, but again, it's only producing one or the other. How do I merge them?

Comment: parentService constains the properties : serviceDescription, and serviceName while childService contains : NaptanCode, StopName, StopId.

Comment: Ok. So with the following: `foreach (var parentService in routeNames)
            {                
                foreach (var childService in parentService.services)
                {
                    listServices.ItemsSource = parentService.services;                    
                }
            } `

What needs to change so I can get all in a list?

Comment: The closest you would get is : foreach (var parentService in routeNames) { listServices.ItemsSource = parentService; foreach (var childService in parentService.services) { listServices.ItemsSource = childService.services; } }.  But ItemSource doesn't work on multi-level objects.